# Getting TypeError during creation of Bar chart from excel using openpyxl.reference

Tags: python-3.x

Getting TypeError during the creation of Bar chart from excel using openpyxl.reference method.

Here is the full code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
 Reference,
 Series,
 BarChart
)

wb = load_workbook('revenue.xlsx')
wsheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sales')
print (wsheet)


data =   Reference(wsheet, (5, 2), (5, 10))
categs = Reference(wsheet, (3, 2), (3, 10))

chart = BarChart()
chart.add_data(data=data)
chart.set_categories(categs)

chart.legend = None
chart.y_axis.majorGridlines = None
chart.varyColors = True
chart.title = "Sales By name"

wsheet.add_chart(chart, "H15")    

wb.save("revenue.xlsx")

print ("end")
```

Getting following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\naif\python\Aura\Aura_Networks___Python___Excel_Parsers\05-chart.py", line 15, in <module>
    data =   Reference(wsheet, (5, 2), (5, 10))
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reference.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.min_col = min_col
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 107, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'int'>
>>>
```

If I add the following lines to replace above lines I don't get that error:

```
data =   Reference(wsheet, min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=10)
categs = Reference(wsheet, min_col=3, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=10)
```

Comment: Have you checked the [Reference class API](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.chart.reference.html?highlight=reference#openpyxl.chart.reference.Reference)? If you initialize a class with the wrong parameters, it is very likely that it won't work